# SQL Azure data warehouse - how to scale in sql when database name contains a hyphen

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

using the below [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-compute-tsql):

```
ALTER DATABASE my-db
MODIFY (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'DW300')
```

but I get

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Parse error at line: 1, column: 16: Incorrect syntax near 'my'

escaping with square brackets gives:

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Parse error at line: 1, column: 16: Incorrect syntax near '[my-db]'

Similarly with single quotes. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query can only be run against the master database on the azure server.

Changing the context to master and re-running works successfully.